# Is there a way to track by Google Analytics users in incognito mode inside iframe?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, google-analytics-4

I tried to implement google analytics tracking by gtag.js library but faced a problem. When users tried to send data from incognito mode nothing coming. First of all, I thought GA doesn't track incognito mode because of some sort of policy restrictions but a more interesting thing happend when the same user came from Edge's incognito mode it was sent perfectly (ofc as a new person).